# How to save a the content into the file with neat alignment?

Tags: php, javascript, html, xml

I am having a textbox, in that i have loaded a xml file.
After editing and saving the xml content into the xml file, the content is not in the right formate.
While loading again, its not in the xml format
How to save a the content into the file with neat alignment?
Please help me
For Example
I need to save like the following

```
<section>
<value>a</value>
<value>b</value>
</section>
```

But after saving its looks like

```
<section><value>a</value><value>b</value></section>
```

Thanks,
Praveen J

Comment: Please rephrase your question to make it more clear. What do you mean by "it's not in the xml format"? Do the elements get stripped or is the XML just not indented/appearing in the same form as in the textbox? More details please. And some code to show what you're actually doing might be helpful, too.

Comment: If you post a sample of what your output actually looks like it would be helpful.

Comment: I have edited the question, hope u can understand now - i am using PHP, javascript, ajax to save the file content.

Answer (score 0):

As Gordon says your question makes no sense - the XML fragment is still "well-formed" (but its far from complete) so it **is** in the right format.

Do you mean you want to preserve the format it was submitted in? In which case output it using <pre>...</pre> tags. OTOH there are standard tools out there which wil format XML according to specific standards - e.g. [geshi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/index.php)

C.

Answer (score 0):

I think is issue is that it doesn't preserve whitespace, so opening the xml file later shows it all in a single line as opposed to spaced/tabbed as originally created.

You can try `white-space: physical` as a CSS attribute on your textarea. Alternatively you can try adding the attribute/value pair "wrap=hard" to your textarea declaration. Both methods should preserve whtepace.